# Module sys has no _MEIPASS member error on Python 3.6.6

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have been trying to bundle a json file in a python executable created with pyinstaller. After a lot of researching, the solution I found involved making use of the _MEIPASS folder; however, VSCode claims that the sys package has no _MEIPASS member.

The relevant part of my code goes like this:

```
branches_path = 'bank_branches/bank_branches.json'

if hasattr(sys, "_MEIPASS"):
     branches_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, branches_path)
```

The code works on the terminal version, as well as on the standalone application, so this is taken care of; however, I'd like to know if there is a solution which works and has no errors associated. If it helps, I'm using Python 3.6.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue when creating an executable using pyinstaller. I had to make two changes to my script in order to get a functional executable.

First, I created this function:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    try: 
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

My script has several classes in it, so I put this at the very end, by itself, so that all classes could reference it. I then replaced any function I had that used

```
os.getcwd()
```

- which was probably a bad idea in the first place - with

```
resource_path()
```

and for the variable inside of resource_path() I used this function instead:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

This function returned what I wanted anyway; the location of THIS file/program that is running.

So, what previously was written like:

```
filePath = os.getcwd() + "\\my_file.csv"
```

Now reads as:

```
filePath = resource_path(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + "\\my_file.csv"
```

Once this was in place, my program compiled correctly and executed as expected, hopefully it can help you as well.

Comment: I'll try it out this weekend, but in the meantime I appreciate your help!

Comment: I have the same problem but at an executable file made with cx_Freeze.  'AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute '_MEIPASS'' . So what could I do in this case ? Thank

Comment: @chaviaras Michalis - did this method not work for you in cx_Freeze? because it should.

Comment: @NL23codes  I had a very big project and I couldn't replace with the above every call. I had the same _MEIPASS problem but at the end I solved it differently. I notice that there was problem with pyocr library and tkinter. I am suspecting either the cx_Freeze or the setup.py I wrote because these two libraries were different in the Python Path and at the folder I made the setup.py. So at the end I can't say to you if this method works for the cx_Freeze because I didn't do this method.