# Exe compiled from python 3.8.5 with tkinter gui throws fatal error on Windows10

Tags: python-3.x, executable

I'm trying to deploy a single file app using python 3.8.5 and a tkinter gui. Using pyinstaller works to create the .exe, but running it immediately returns Fatal Error. My environment **Windows 10, Atom IDE, python 3.8.5, tkinter gui**

There are 8 mp4 videos the gui buttons should be able to launch from the gui. I implemented a media folder to hold all the media files in the dev environment can't figure out how to call them in the script.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
from os import startfile
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import win32com.client as win32

# cwd = os.getcwd()
# cfig = cwd + "/aws_guide/config.ini"  # declares the path to the videos
# print(cfig)


class Vp:
    img = '/aws_guide/media/skllp.png'
    ast = 'Accessing the Workspace for the first time.mp4'
    favs = 'Import Bookmarks.mp4'
    otds = 'Logging off-Disconnecting-Rebooting.mp4'
    ntdriv = "C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/Navigating Network Drives.mp4"
    oot = "C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/Outlook Tour.mp4"
    pwrt = "C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/Reset your password.mp4"
    aoot = "C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/Setting up Outlook for the 1st time.mp4"
    findie = "C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/Finding IE.mp4"
    ptm = "mrhoda@innovativecomp.com;awspilot@stuartkane.com"
    kath = "kking@stuartkane.com;mrhoda@innovativecomp.com;awspilot@stuartkane.com"


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        load = Image.open(Vp.img)
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img = Label(self, image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x=0, y=0)
        ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")


def ICShelp(ptm):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = ptm
    mail.Subject = "Workspaces Help"
    mail.HtmlBody = ""
    mail.Display(True)


def imanhelp(kath):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = kath
    mail.Subject = "iManage Help"
    mail.HtmlBody = ""
    mail.Display(True)


def err():
    # lazy error handler
    pass


def close():
    sys.exit()


root = Tk()
root.title("Getting to Know AWS Workspaces")
app = Window(root)
root.geometry("1048x600")  # good enough for now
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
ttk.Button(app, text="Getting Started with Workspaces", command=lambda: startfile(Vp.ast)).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(app, text="Setup Outlook", command=lambda: startfile(Vp.aoot)).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(app, text="Tour Outlook", command=lambda: startfile(Vp.oot)).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(app, text="How to Reset Your Password", command=lambda: startfile(Vp.pwrt)).grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(app, text="How to Find Internet Explorer", command=lambda: startfile(Vp.findie)).grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(app, text="Clone Your Browser Favorites", command=lambda: startfile(Vp.favs)).grid(column=1, row=6, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(app, text="Navigating Your Folders", command=lambda: startfile(Vp.ntdriv)).grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(app, text="Login/Logout Or Disconnect", command=lambda: startfile(Vp.otds)).grid(column=1, row=8, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(app, text="I need ICS Help", command=lambda: ICShelp(Vp.ptm)).grid(column=1, row=9, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(app, text="I need iManage Help", command=lambda: imanhelp(Vp.kath)).grid(column=1, row=10, sticky=W)


root.mainloop()
close()
```

It runs perfectly from Atom. This is my 1st python with a gui. Much appreciated!

Adendum:
Thanks Cool Cloud!
It's compiled with

```
pyinstaller --onefile 
--add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/media/skllp.png;.' 
--add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/media/Accessing the Workspace for the first time.mp4;.'
--add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/media/Finding IE.mp4;.' 
--add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/media/Import Bookmarks.mp4;.' 
--add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/media/Logging off-Disconnecting-Rebooting.mp4;.' 
--add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/media/Navigating Network Drives.mp4;.' 
--add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/media/Outlook Tour.mp4;.' 
--add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/media/Rest your password.mp4;.' 
--add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/media/Setting up Outlook for the 1st time.mp4;.' awstrainer.py
```

I got this in the Traceback:

```
C:\Users\mrhoda>C:\Users\mrhoda\Documents\scripts\aws_guide\dist\awstrainer.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "awstrainer.py", line 74, in <module>
  File "awstrainer.py", line 37, in __init__
  File "PIL\Image.py", line 2878, in open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/aws_guide/media/skllp.png'
[13800] Failed to execute script awstrainer
```

Comment: Did you copy the exe from dist folder to the project directory? Also how did you compile it to an exe? `pyinstaller`? `cxfreeze` ? `auto-py-to-exe`? Whats the line of code used. If its `pyinstaller` then make a new exe by saying `pyinstaller -c -F script.py` and post the error code that comes up in the console.

Comment: Thanks Cool Cloud!

Comment: Would be better to update the Q with this

Comment: Can you say `print(cfig)` and tell me what it is? And does this issue happen when you run the script.py or just when using exe?

Comment: Yup, the maddening thing is it works just fine running the .py file, but fails as a .exe. I'm putting it together to help a bunch of users who can barely tie their shoes so it's gotta be click-n-run simple.

Comment: Line 23 is where the error is at, `img = config.get('FILES', 'img')` maybe the path becomes invalid or something, try `print(cfig)` to make sure that its what you want.

Comment: print(cfig) shows exactly what it should for the path. All components are in the same folder, but is it possible pyinstaller is not grabbing the config.ini file as part of the package?

Comment: One problem is that `img=C:\Users\mrhoda\Documents\scripts\aws_guide\img.png` is that there is ' \ ' which means escape characters, so is it possible to replace that with ' \\ ' or ' / ' ?

Comment: I changed all the paths to use '/' for consistency. Everything still works from Atom, but it's the exact same Traceback from the exe.

Comment: Im not able to relate to this error. try running the py file from the location of the exe file, does any errors come from the py file now?

Comment: I got mad and completely stripped out the config file import, reset class VP to be the variables = absolute paths.......it works as .exe now!

It didn't package any of the content so I still can't send it out yet, but it at least runs and pulls from those absolute paths.
Thanks @CoolCloud !

Comment: Hmmmm thats sad, but eventually youll find a way, all the best!

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't calling the relative paths correctly for the pyinstaller. Thanks again @CoolCloud for looking at this thing! Kudos to @NL23codes, your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197722/module-sys-has-no-meipass-member-error-on-python-3-6-6) got me to the finish line.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
import os
from os import startfile
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import win32com.client as win32


def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(
        sys,
        '_MEIPASS',
        os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


class Vp():
    Logo = resource_path("skllp.png")
    ast = resource_path("Accessing the Workspace for the first time.mp4")
    favs = resource_path("Import Bookmarks.mp4")
    otds = resource_path("Logging off-Disconnecting-Rebooting.mp4")
    ntdriv = resource_path("Navigating Network Drives.mp4")
    oot = resource_path("Outlook Tour.mp4")
    pwrt = resource_path("Reset your password.mp4")

.....etc
```

It still took a big pyinstaller command

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/skllp.png;.' --add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/Accessing the Workspace for the first time.mp4;.'--add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/Finding IE.mp4;.' --add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/Import Bookmarks.mp4;.' --add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/Logging off-Disconnecting-Rebooting.mp4;.' --add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/Navigating Network Drives.mp4;.' --add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/Outlook Tour.mp4;.' --add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/Rest your password.mp4;.' --add-data 'C:/Users/mrhoda/Documents/scripts/aws_guide/Setting up Outlook for the 1st time.mp4;.' awstrainer.py
```

But it does work now. The relative path part was the key.